# How to workaround MongoDB's current limitation of just one geospatial index per collection?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

Currently, MongoDB supports only [one geospatial index per collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CreatingtheIndex). How can I workaround this manually?

Is there some smart way to emulate this kind of index without losing too much accuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably can create a second collection, which will hold only the (same) object-id, and the secondary geospatial index.

when you want to query for the secondary index, you'd query that second collection, get the list of ids back, and then query the master collection by ids.

Comment: I was hoping for some solution where I could do that in just one step, but I think that in fact this probably is the only way.Thank you, @ken.